# How to hold an array of GMSPlace

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, google-places-api

For an individual PlaceID, google provides the follow piece of code which works perfectly -

```
let placeID = "ChIJV4k8_9UodTERU5KXbkYpSYs"
```

however, if I attempt an array like

```
let mexican: GMSPlace = ["ChIJM8S9ACvoIogRmzYiLgzlP_g",
"ChIJwSHwoNTpIogRyElYj-kHC14",
"ChIJDWRMYifoIogR7S6U4tryodY",
"ChIJqSVd6yfoIogRmTgBSoO4Z0k",
"ChIJLacWlinoIogRVGYk-bZbGUE",
"ChIJSUC9S2zCIogRTKyiW0q_6tI"]
```

the contextual type can't be used with the literal array. How can I make a an array holding GMSPlaceID's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare an array of `String` instead:

```
let mexican: [String] = ["ChIJM8S9ACvoIogRmzYiLgzlP_g",
"ChIJwSHwoNTpIogRyElYj-kHC14",
"ChIJDWRMYifoIogR7S6U4tryodY",
"ChIJqSVd6yfoIogRmTgBSoO4Z0k",
"ChIJLacWlinoIogRVGYk-bZbGUE",
"ChIJSUC9S2zCIogRTKyiW0q_6tI"]
```

So instead of:

```
let mexican: GSMPlace
```

Use:

```
let mexican: [String]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the new error is "cannot convert value of type string to expected element type gmsplace"

Comment: Expected that, try `let mexican: [String]` instead.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I guess my mind is going right now after thinking about it too much. Strings are only needed to iniate the LookUpPlaceID and only the GMSPlace type is needed to save the result.

Comment: @jonpeter, easily happened :)